# Content not showing up by default with exposed filters

Tags: views

I have a view with 2 taxonomy term fields. I have these fields presented as expose filters for site users to select from dropdown, which works fine. However, when I first land onto the view page, none of my content is showing up. All I see is a blank view. 
However, if I click apply, with all the fields unselected (e.g. - Any -), then all my content shows up. How do I make the content show up by default without having to click on Apply?

Upon landing on the page for the first time:
[image: upon landing on page]

After clicking Search:
[image: after clicking apply]

Comment: In view by default it will show all data. Can u  share your views settings page screeshot here?

Comment: Overall views settings:
http://cl.ly/image/3w1R1u0l3g3W

Comment: Expose filter settings:
http://cl.ly/image/0a3s0p1i1P12

Answer (score 1):

In exposed filter section try to deselect all values in **Select terms from vocabulary Event type** field